# How to build calf endurance?

Tags: training, judo

## Injury prevention within the context of martial arts training

**Goal:**

During the randoris, I am not always able to finish due to cramps on calves.

**Question:**

What proven routines can I do to build my calf endurance to last till the end of the randori. My goal is to be able to finish at least 5 randoris.

**Side Note:**

I am currently practicing/training every morning, doing jump rope or running.

Comment: This isn't a medical forum. Cramps can be caused by any number of mostly minor and some dangerous medical conditions. The fact that you say this happens invariably, and presumably you've been doing it for a long period of time, means something potentially serious might be happening here. I would make an appointment with a sports medicine doctor (MD) if you could. They'll want to rule out some of these serious causes and may offer suggestions on how to avoid it in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to post my question on a body-building forum to ask some [exercises](http://bodybuilding.com/fun/wotw50.htm) to ramp up the calf. (But I would have preferred to dodge the use of machine)

Comment: There are a lot of potential causes for cramps: dehydration, blood flow problems, lack of minerals like potassium or calcium in your blood, exposure to cold temperatures, injury or overuse of your muscles, certain diseases related to your kidney or thyroid, medication like diuretics, birth control pills, steroids.
So instead of fighting the symptoms, try to find out the cause (in other words, go see a doctor).

Comment: Thanks. These ones maybe the cause: dehydration, lack of potassium, cold temperatures, overuse of the muscles. So, drinking, eating chocolate/banana, asking to rise up heating and empowering calf muscle would respectively make it. And the last one was the matter of my question: empower the calf muscle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to class more. Drink more water in the 8 to 12 hours before training so that you're not dehydrated in class. Stretch your calves when you wake up and in your warm-up for judo class.

Don't look to bodybuilding for answers; their training methods are inappropriate for a judoka. Even strength training is almost certainly unnecessary: the problem is sport-specific and unless you've been seeing this problem for more than six months of judo training it's due to being unconditioned *for judo*, not some deficiency in your calves.

Comment: Thanks. Going to class more is a good  idea, I will think about it.

Comment: You might also want to look at adjusting your potassium levels. Cramps can be a sign of to little or to much vitamin k. When my levels are off it usually manifests in my calves.

Answer (score 0):

Among the many exercises the most suitable is jump rope.
[Source](http://www.wikihow.com/Build-Calf-Muscle-Without-Equipment)

> When you use a jump rope, your calf is constantly engaged. This helps
>   build muscle, provides a good cardiovascular workout and makes you
>   quicker on your feet as well. Do this exercise regularly, and see why
>   you don’t need weight equipment to tone your calf muscles.